# How Can JPEG Be Used to Realize a Transfer Application with a Fixed Bit Rate?

Tags: image-processing, compression, image-compression, jpeg

For simplicity, assume a fixed bandwidth (`5MB/s`) and that each second an image with `12MP` is generated. The quality of the image should be as high as possible (in terms of PSNR). Which compression rate is necessary and how would the task differ or become simplified when using `JPEG 2000` instead?

### Thoughts

When the image is a colored image with 24bpp, then the size of a `12MP` image would be `12*10^6*24/8 Byte` = `36 MB`. That divided by `5MB` yields a compression rate of approximately `7`. Then transferring works as desired. However, I don't see how the task changes when using `JPEG 2000`.

Comment: so, what have you figured out so far? What's the problem you're having answering this yourself?

Comment: When the image is in grayscale then the size of a 12MP image would be `12*10^6/8` Byte. That divided by `5MB` yields a compression rate of 300. Then transferring works as desired. However, I don't see how the problem changes when using `JPEG` or `JPEG 2000`.

Comment: why do you even assume the problem changes? Give context for your question!

Comment: I mean, why the task becomes simpler when using `JPEG 2000`? Does the compression rate shrink? Can't be, right?

Comment: That's three new questions. What I'm saying is: Please edit your question to make clear all of your thoughts leading to the question you're asking. Your comments are mostly incoherent to me.

Comment: The question remains the same: `JPEG` vs. `JPEG 2000`. I have edited my question. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: as said, your comments are mostly incoherent, copying and pasting them to your question doesn't help at all. For example, where does you $12\cdot 10^6 / 8$ come from? It seems wrong. As I already asked **why** do you even ask yourself about the difference between JPEG and JPEG2000 in this context?

Comment: 12 megapixels are 12,000,000 bits, no? Under the assumption that a pixel can either be black or white. Otherwise, there would be an additional constant (factor) for adding more values per pixel, however, that doesn't change the sense. I don't know what's the difference between JPEG and JPEG2000 in this context, if I would know, I would not ask. Ultimately, this was an exam question, which claims that JPEG2000 simplifies the task.

Comment: grayscale != black and white. And JPEG doesn't even have a black-and-white mode. *Research*, and *test your hypotheses*. It's not like you don't have access to programs that can write JPEG files...

Comment: but I repeat: **WHY** do you even think this changes with different compression methods?

Comment: Ok, then assume RGB with 24bpp, thus `12*10^6*3*24/8`, which doesn't change **anything** except the stupid number that represents the compression rate.
And I repeat: Ultimately, this was an exam question, which claims that JPEG2000 simplifies the task.

Comment: Ok, this is getting boring. I've asked three times now (four counting this comment) *why* you even think JPEG vs JPEG2000 makes a difference. Since you're not willing to explain the reason you think it does, there's little sense in discussing any further (also, you mentioning the RGB color space demonstrates you haven't even read the JPEG wikipedia page – that really warrants the downvote for insufficient research on your other question). So, I think, I can't really help you – and will be leaving your questions alone.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And I write this the third time now: Ultimately, this was an exam question, which claims that JPEG2000 simplifies the task.

Comment: I'm trying to more or less gently point out that you're not really thinking hard enough. Try to understand the exam question – it gives another condition aside from the rate; you're ignoring that.

Comment: Obviously, I miss something. Another thought I had, was that it is possible to specify the compression-factor explicitly in `JPEG 2000`, maybe that makes the task simpler. I don't know... Sorry for my stupidity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculated the needed compression ratio correctly.
Now to answer the rest of the question:

1. The JPEG Algorithm doesn't let you set the size of the output file only the Quality measure. Namely to ensure the size of the output is close to the limit (Namely highest quality) requires trial and error (Though using the Quality you can get a measure of the bits per color).
   The JPEG 2000 on the other hand allows you to cut the data at the exact number of bytes required hence makes the task much simpler (You can practically set a threshold on the output size).
2. The image quality of JPEG at compression ratio of ~100 is really bad (See Wikipedia article on [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)). While JPEG 2000 can get better results.

To understand the Quality in JPEG, have a look at [How JPG Works by Colt McAnlis](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-jpg-works-a4dbd2316f35):

[image]

Pay attention to the line:

> Probably most important, is that the quality parameter varies depending on the image. Since each image is unique, and presents different types of visual artifacts, the Q value will be unique as well.

This is what JPEG 2000 makes easier.

Comment: I noticed a mistake in the compression rate calculation. Let's assume a color image with 24bpp, then it would be `12*10^6*24/8 B` = `36 MB` divided through `5 MB` yields approx. a compression rate of 7, right? I edited it above.

Comment: It doesn't change the difference between JPEG and JPEG 2000 in that respect.

Comment: True. I just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

A very good article on JPEG 2000 is

> A. Skodras, C. Christopoulos and T. Ebrahimi, "The JPEG 2000 still
>   image compression standard," in IEEE Signal Processing Magazine, vol.
>   18, no. 5, pp. 36-58, Sep 2001. doi: 10.1109/79.952804 Abstract: One
>   of the aims of the standardization committee has been the development
>   of Part I, which could be used on a royalty- and fee-free basis. This
>   is important for the standard to become widely accepted. The
>   standardization process, which is coordinated by the JTCI/SC29/WG1 of
>   the ISO/IEC has already produced the international standard (IS) for
>   Part I. In this article the structure of Part I of the JPFG 2000
>   standard is presented and performance comparisons with established
>   standards are reported. This article is intended to serve as a
>   tutorial for the JPEG 2000 standard. The main application areas and
>   their requirements are given. The architecture of the standard follows
>   with the description of the tiling, multicomponent transformations,
>   wavelet transforms, quantization and entropy coding. Some of the most
>   significant features of the standard are presented, such as
>   region-of-interest coding, scalability, visual weighting, error
>   resilience and file format aspects. Finally, some comparative results
>   are reported and the future parts of the standard are discussed
>   keywords: {ISO standards;code standards;data compression;entropy
>   codes;image coding;quantisation
>   (signal);reviews;standardisation;telecommunication standards;transform
>   coding;wavelet transforms;ISO/IEC;JPEG 2000 still image compression
>   standard;Part I standard;entropy coding;error resilience;file
>   format;image tiling;international standard;multicomponent
>   transformations;performance
>   comparisons;quantization;region-of-interest
>   coding;scalability;standardization committee;visual weighting;wavelet
>   transforms;Entropy coding;IEC standards;ISO standards;Image
>   coding;Quantization;Resilience;Scalability;Standardization;Transform
>   coding;Wavelet transforms}, URL:
>   http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=952804&isnumber=20598

There are other JPEG2000 papers in this SP magazine edition.

It is in some ways a transport layer as much as a file standard.  It is designed to support many display resolutions over a network.  Another network feature is that is builds an image as it is received over a network. If the transport terminates, some of the image is registered at the destination.  One doesn't need a complete file to display an image.

The Region of Interest is treated as an elevated bit plane that is transmitted first. You have the option of lossy or lossless compression.